# Stimulus controller: event listened multiple times; how do I remove event listeners and retain the Context?

Tags: javascript, event-listener, stimulusjs

I've got the following controller on my HTML page:

```
...
<div data-controller="parent">
    <div data-target="parent.myDiv">
        <div data-controller="child">
            <span data-target="child.mySpan"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

This child controller is mapped to the following `child_controller.js` class:

```
export default class {
    static targets = ["mySpan"];

    connect() {
        document.addEventListener("myEvent", (event) => this.handleMyEvent(event));
    }

    handleMyEvent(event) {
        console.log(event);
        this.mySpanTarget; // Manipulate the span. No problem.
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is an event listener on the `connect()` of the Stimulus controller, and when it detects that the event was fired up, it logs the event and manipulates the span target.

The problem arises when I replace the contents of the target `myDiv` from my `parent_controller.js`:

```
...
let childControllerHTML = "<div data-controller="child">...</div>"

myDivTarget.innerHTML= childControllerHTML;
...
```

Now that the `myEvent` gets fired up, the event listener picks it not once, but twice (because the same event got logged twice). With every subsequent replacement of the child HTML, the event gets logged one more time than it did before.

I know that one can make use of `document.removeEventListener` to prevent the old controller from still listening to the events:

```
export default class {
    static targets = ["mySpan"];

    connect() {
        this.myEventListener = document.addEventListener("myEvent", (event) => this.handleMyEvent(event));
    }

    disconnect() {
        document.removeEventListener("myEvent", this.myEventListener);
    }

    handleMyEvent(event) {
        console.log(event);
        this.mySpanTarget; // FAILS. Can't find span.
    }
}
```

But doing it like this makes the `handleMyEvent` method lose the `context` as it no longer finds the `mySpanTarget` under `this`.

How can I remove the listener from the child controller to which I already got no access as it is no longer in the DOM, while retaining the context?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer on [StimulusJS's Discourse page](https://discourse.stimulusjs.org/t/remove-listen-to-animation-end/528/3).

One has to make use of the `bind` method when initializing the controller:

```
export default class {
    static targets = ["mySpan"];

    initialize() {
        this.boundHandleMyEvent = this.handleMyEvent.bind(this);
    }

    connect() {
        document.addEventListener("myEvent", this.boundHandleMyEvent);
    }

    disconnect() {
        document.removeEventListener("myEvent", this.boundHandleMyEvent);
    }

    handleMyEvent(event) {
        console.log(event);
        this.mySpanTarget; // Manipulate the span. No problem.
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, the event is only listened once, and the context is not lost inside the `handleMyEvent` method.

Comment: Would this.element.addEventListener be better (limit scope, more efficient) than document.addEventListener?

Comment: @TacTacelosky good comment, make this a answer is a good one